# StableBaselines3 neural network - why does performance drop/destabilize when I call model.learn() a second time?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am using StableBaselines3 (based on PyTorch) to train a neural network for a Reinforcement Learning task.

I am using Tensorboard to log the mean episode reward to track the training progress. However, I noticed something that doesn't make sense to me.

Below is a screenshot of some training:
[image]

The red line is the mean episode reward when, after creating my model through model=PPO(..), I called model.learn(500000). The blue line is the mean episode reward when, after the first model.learn(500000) finished training, I called model.learn(500000) again, which I thought would just continue the training where the previous model.learn() left off.

Why is there such a steep drop (and also instability) in the initial performance of the 2nd model.learn() run?

Comment: Did you dump/save model state in between? If so, there could be something missing in the dump, so that the loaded model does not properly continue training. Make sure you properly save the model state. Ref, see [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-a-general-checkpoint-for-inference-and-or-resuming-training).

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about which parts of the model and the optimizer were saved and restored, it is impossible to tell what caused this behavior.

The most likely explanation is that only the weights of the actor-critic were stored, but not those related to exploration. When training a policy using PPO we usually add action noise to the output of the actor network in order to achieve exploration. Gaussian or uniform noise is a very common choice for this. The plot looks like the noise parameters were initialized with relatively high default values in the second run. The optimizer then rapidly drove these values back down to low values at which point the policy started to behave more deterministic again, achieving relatively constant mean episode reward.

In order to debug these issues, you want to plot the magnitude of the action noise. In this case, it likely starts at a high value for the second run and reaches (approximately) the values it had at the end of first run at iteration ~150k in the second run.